# SIF 2.0 Installation Failed - Invalid Web URI

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Recent Sitecore 9.1 Initial Release had launched with SIF 2.0. As per documentation you need to execute following command. Assuming here you are doing first time on your machine.

```
Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v3
```

But this gives me error on my local machine & tried also in my remote fresh Azure Windows Server 2016 machine. Following is error

```
PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : Module Repository 'SitecoreGallery' exists.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:4173 char:17
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource @PSBoundParamete ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (Microsoft.Power...erPackageSource:RegisterPackageSource) [Register-PackageSource], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageSourceExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.RegisterPackageSource
```

Comment: I think SIF 2.0 was only available as a zip file and not on NuGet yet. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Issue is Something wrong with this URL as one browser hit it doesn't show Packages while V2 version did. https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this error if have are using internet through proxy which requires credentials. Avoid using the proxy or provide proxy credentials to the PS command.

Answer (score 6):

Solution is mentioned already in other Sitecore 9.1 Installation Guide. Install Old SIF & update it.

```
Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2
```

If you already have SIF you can directly update it by following command

```
Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
```

You can verify it by running following command

```
Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework –ListAvailable
```

It should look like in fresh machines like this
[image]

In Existing machines after just updates it should like this
[image]